# Using column names from another table to define the name of a new table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm looking to create a new table name as the name of the column in a previous table but it can't seem to recognize the @table_name_2 variable. I'm trying to do the following;

```
DECLARE @table_name_2 varchar(MAX)

SET @table_name_2 = 
(select
col.name as column_name
from sys.tables as tab
inner join sys.columns as col
on tab.object_id = col.object_id
left join sys.types as t
on col.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
where schema_name(tab.schema_id) = 'Staging' and tab.name = 'QACalculator' and col.column_id = 2)

CREATE TABLE @table_name_2
(
MI_KEY NOT NULL
ISSUE NULL
)
```

Comment: Variables can't be used to replace a literal value. If you *must* do this you'll have to use dynamic SQL and ***safely*** inject the names of the objects into your statement. Also, there's no need to declare it as a `varchar(MAX)`, an object's name will never contain 2 Billion characters. Use `sysname` (a synonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`).

Comment: This has a pretty bad design smell to it. Why do you need to dynamically name a table but you know the schema, table name and the ordinal position of the column? This has [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) all over it.

Comment: The fact that the OP has the id of the column, and *not* the name is the really odd part. I agree, this has the smell of an XY Problem, @SeanLange . The OP telling us what the problem that are *actually* trying to solve will shed some light on this.

Comment: Creating tables is usually a design time task. It's very rare to find good reasons to do it at runtime.